# Projecting Conical Helix on Cone in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, geometry

[image] [image]

> Suppose you have `f(x)=x-floor(x)`.
>
> [image]
>
> By this, you can generate the grooves by gluing the top side and the
> bottom side together and then squeezing the left to zero -- now you
> have a conical helix: the line spins around the cone until it hits the
> bottom. You already have one form of the equations for the conical
> helix namely `x=a*cos(a); y=a*sin(a); z=a`. Now like
> [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7868186#7868186):
>
> **How can you project the conical helix on the cone in Matlab?**

Comment: I suppose you are looking for `1./( t .* sin(t) )` and not `sin(t)./t`? The way you wrote that expression, Matlab would interpret it as a latter one.

Comment: @zplesivcak perhaps, I don't know yet -- I am trying to understand how to twist the surface of the cone first i.e. to add the fluctuation term. I like to think it only as a projection along the surface but then I need to find out somehow the normal vector of the surface in each point, thinking. Perhaps I think this too mathematically?!

Comment: `1./( t .* sin(t) )` is really awful looking function with lots of poles, so I think that you need `sin(t)./t` ...

Comment: if indeed zplesivcak is right, then you can also use `sinc`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd approach your problem without using `plot3`, instead I'd use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`sinc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinc.html). Note that `sinc` is a matlab built in functions that just do `sin(x)./x`, for example:

[image]

So in 1-D, if I understand you correctly you want to "project" `sinc(x)` on `sqrt(x.^2)`. The problem with your question is that you mention projection with the dot product, but a dot product reduces the dimensionality, so a dot product of two vectors gives a scalar, and of two 2D surfaces - a vector, so I don't understand what you mean. From the 2-D plot you added  I interpreted the question as to "dress" one function with the other, like in addition...

Here's the implementation:

```
N=64;
[x y]=meshgrid(linspace(-3*pi,3*pi,N),linspace(-3*pi,3*pi,N));
t=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
f=t+2*sinc(t);

subplot(1,2,1)
mesh(x,y,f) ;      axis vis3d

subplot(1,2,2)
mesh(x,y,f)
view(0,0) ;  axis square
colormap bone
```

[image]

The factor `2` in the `sinc` was placed for better visualization of the fluctuations of the `sinc`.

Comment: I cannot understand `"t=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);"` -- does it have now greater fluctuation on the peak and smaller near the broad area? This `"t=f=t+2*sinc(t).*t"` makes it look oscillating the same along the surface -- perhaps now too large oscillation? I have to still study this to understand. I tried `f=1./t+2*sinc(t)` but getting far to large peak, testing...

Comment: `t` is just the radius, meaning `z(x,y)=sqrt(x^2+y^2)=t` will yield a cone. As for `sinc`, I'm not sure if that is the function you meant, but you can read about it in the documentation in the link, I've also added a plot of it in the answer. Why did you multiplied `t*sinc` in your comment? doing so you end up with the regular `sin` and not `sinc`...

Comment: Missing the screw-shape (the hand-drawn picture), the pointy head and descending fluctuation from the broad area to top (top with the smallest amplitude) -- tried `f=t+2*fliplr(sinc(t))` but not workingn -- still debugging, perhaps solving things myself but taking some time.

Comment: `sinc` is a symmetric function, `fliplr` won't change it. I think you need to first find the function that will do what you need, it see,s that `sinc` is not it. maybe you need something like `f=t+exp(-t/a).*cos(b*t)`;